# Retrieving json data in php

Tags: php, json

Sending data to php through js like this:

```
 var data= {
    "name":name,
    "company":company,
    "phone":phone,
     };      
var jsonText = JSON.stringify(data);
 ajax.open("POST", "../../abc/google.php", false);
ajax.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
ajax.send("totalJsonStr="+jsonText);
alert(jsonText);
return true;
```

EDIT:

trying to retrieve like this:

```
$jsonVal = json_decode($_POST["totalJsonStr"]);

//echo $jsonVal2->{'name'}; 
$name=  $jsonVal->{'name'};
```

Cant seem to retrieve. The name field always comes blank.

Comment: Have you checked for json errors? http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error.php

You probably need to URL encode the jsonText before sending it. What does the $totalJsonStr contain?

Comment: Include the following in your question, and you might be able to answer your own quesiton...


var_dump($totalJsonStr);
var_dump($jsonVal2)

Comment: Did you already set `$totalJsonStr = $_POST['totalJsonStr']` ?

Comment: Check `$totalJsonStr` to make sure it is as you expect it to be.

Comment: @Rohit: no, I dint...

Comment: just sent the `params` no need to do `json_stringify` and then you can get the name

Comment: can someone suggest me a solution??

Comment: @Broken: tried that...

Comment: @stylojack_10 you have to do it as Rohit suggested. First store your data in some variable $var =$_POST['$totalJsonStr']; then do rest of work on $var

Comment: echo `$jsonVal2->name`;

Comment: @NemanjaLazic with braces {} it is fine. It will work

Comment: @stylojack_10: please see my answer below.

Comment: @stylojack_10 if still not working can you please post var_dump($_POST["totalJsonStr"])

Comment: The form gets submitted before var_dump($_POST["totalJsonStr"]) can execute...

Comment: ^ then how were you able to echo the name ? How is this setup, is the php within the same file or...?

Comment: its in a different file. I wanst able to, I was trying to echo....

Comment: its there in the code: ajax.open("post", url, false)

Comment: So, are you just opening the php file to see the results? That will not display anything because as you said the form gets submitted. The only way you can display it is if you put the php within the same file as the html/javascript code. The data is probably being passed properly to the php file and you can do whatever you want with the data, like store in a database but you cannot display the data in the browser by loading the php file.

Comment: the data isnt going to the database. thats what i am trying to do...

Comment: also i am checking with if(isset($_POST['totalJsonStr'])) 
  {}else{die "blah"} in my .php. It always dies.

Comment: Personally, I would suggest using jquery's .ajax()/.post() function and .done() function to see if the ajax function is executing or not, and to see the result of the ajax response. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/